# how to implement ElasticSearch in Flask app?

Tags: python, flask, elasticsearch

I wrote a Python Flask app and want to integrate ElasticSearch in this for effective search. But there is not tuts/docs available regarding integrating ElasticSearch in flask app..

Please refer any tuts/docs if available? Or any instructions.

Regards

Comment: I'm assuming you already have an idea of how to use Flask. So your next step is to learn how to use ElasticSearch. Do this in a temporary script somewhere, playing around with the API and learning how it works. Then, use that API in your Flask app. I think you might see extensions such as "Flask-SQLAlchemy" and think that there must be some magic that ties these large frameworks together. Flask-SQLAlchemy and other extensions help, but Flask views are just Python, and you can run any python code in it.

Answer (score 5):

[Here's a module](https://github.com/jcrafford/flask-elasticsearch) which extends `flask` to use `ElasticSearch`. It's actually just a very thin wrapper around [pyelasticsearch](https://github.com/rhec/pyelasticsearch), which does all the heavy lifting.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/chiangf/Flask-Elasticsearch) repository seems to have the updated/maintained version of the code for `Flask` & `Elasticsearch`